# kube-rbac-proxy with kube-state-metrics and prometheus

Tags: kubernetes

I know kube-rbac-proxy can be used for restricting access to kube-state-metrics, with authentication done using tokens. I know it needs to be done using by enabling kubeRBACProxy.enabled=true Now, how do I configure the prometheus to actually use the correct token to be passed to kube-rbac-proxy so that it can scrape from kube-state-metrics?